# Hot key to type today's date?

Tags: shortcut-keys, date

Is there some way to set up a hot key that will type today's date into the current window as if I had typed it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, using a text-expander program such as *AutoKey*.

- Install `autokey-gtk` from the software center, or from the terminal via `sudo apt-get install autokey-gtk`.
- Open AutoKey from the dash, expand the "Sample Scripts" on the left, select "Insert Date", set a hotkey for it and save. That's it!

  [image]

Comment: Thank you! I changed "date" to "date '+%A %B %d %Y'" which results in Wednesday September 26 2012. But there is one strange thing - when I use it with TreePad (a Windows program running in Wine) I get wednesday september 26 2012 (note lower case). Any idea why that is happening?

Comment: Yes, it happens with notepad.exe, which makes me suspect wine. I also used it as input directly into wine (as the name of my "organization") and got lower-case letters there too.

Comment: Let me install Wine and look into it...

Comment: I didn't solve the date problem that I get when using AutoKey with Wine, but I worked around it by switching to TreePad beta for Linux.

Comment: Nice, I used autokey-gtk and set a shortcut of `Alt + Shift + D` as per https://defkey.com/what-means/alt-shift-d. Also changed the command to `date --iso` as per my preference!